# Problem with fuerte version of ROS

Tags: ros, turtlesim, ros-fuerte, roswtf, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, i'm just starting to learn ROS, but i'm having some problems following the tutorials:
1- The Turtlesim windows was supposed to show a turtle, but mine just shows the blue color. What did i do wrong? Or is it because i'm using the beta version of ROS (fuerte)?

2- The command "rosmsg show " doesn't work! every time i try it, it shows me:
"Cannot locate message [Num] in package [beginner_tutorials] with paths [/home/beto/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/msg]", but in this folder there is the msg Num.msg, what am I doing wrong?

3- The command "roswtf" tells me: "ROS_ROOT is invalid: ROS_ROOT [/opt/ros/fuerte] must end is directory named 'ros'", but this is the directory, i dont know why its telling me this.

One last thing, the tutorial tells me to execute this file: setup.sh, that contains this text:
" #!/bin/sh
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte
export PATH=$ROS_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$ROS_ROOT/core/roslib/src:$PYTHONPATH
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/ros_workspace"

But i'm not sure this is the version for the fuerte version of Ros, because i just copied the electric version and changed a little bit so it would work on ros, maybe that's why im having those problems.

Thanks everyone.. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30367/problem-with-fuerte-version-of-ros.../) by [BetoCC011](https://answers.ros.org/users/2041/betocc011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BetoCC011](https://answers.ros.org/users/2041/betocc011/) on 2012-03-23**:
I'm using fuerte because my teacher recommended :) I'm doing my scientific initiation and he needs me to know how to use the fuerte version, how different are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably shouldn't be using Fuerte, which is not yet released, if you are still learning ROS.  At a glance, there are numerous possible configuration issues in your setup and they probably aren't worth debugging, given that you can just use Electric.  Fuerte will be released in mid-April.

Update: Fuerte is very different at the package system level, so configuration is completely different.  It is backwards compatible with Electric, but the configuration comes from entirely different files, so you are likely to encounter issues if you attempt a straight 1-to-1 conversion of your environment setup.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5